# What is the correct way to properly quote and cite a foreign language resource?

Tags: writing-style, citation, style-manuals, foreign-phrases, quoting

Should I provide my own translation? If so, where?

It is important for this particular quote to appear directly: it is the crux of the argument.

Comment: It's a good question, but I'm not sure it is a good match for this site (might be off-topic). Seems more like a question about *style*, whose answer would depend on the particular style guide you intend to follow etc.

Comment: @Drew my other option was [Academia](http://academia.stackexchange.com/), as this question does not seem to be mutually exclusive between those forums. The tags that I used, however unpopular they may be, were not created by me, and seem to be accepted topics in this forum. I *do* use a tag for a particular style (APA), although in reality,a proper citation guide for any would be helpful.

Comment: With luck, some knowledgeable moderator or other user will make a helpful suggestion about where this belongs, how best to tag it, etc.

Comment: @erasmortg [Writers](http://writers.stackexchange.com/) can be the right place. There is a _style_ tag.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano ah! Very well. Hopefully a moderator can migrate the question if they see fit.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about citation formatting. Migrate to Writer's SE. They do citation questions there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good source of information on this is surely [The Chicago Manual of Style](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/16/ch13/ch13_toc.html), which has a comprehensive section on foreign-language quotations (see §13.71-§13.79).

> Should I provide my own translation?

This mainly depends on the intended readers. However, if the piece of text to be quoted is not too long, providing a translation can do no harm (if the translation is accurate).

> If so, where?

If you expect your readers to be fluent in the foreign language and you don't want to interrupt the flow of your text, you can report the translation in a note. Otherwise, it is probably better to report the translation within parentheses directly after the original quotation.