# Is it "allowed" to use a translated quote like as if they were said in English?

Tags: translation, quotes, quoting

As far as I learned you need can quote word by word, showing changes like this:

Albert Einstein: "The Internet is a great invention."

Albert Einstein mentioned, that "[t]he Internet[sic] is a great invention." (Source)

OR you quote indirectly, like:

Albert Einstein is of the oppinion the internet is a great invention, as stated in the source.

But what if Albert Einstein, like the German that he was, spoke it in German? Would I be allowed to quote the translation word by word or would I have to paraphrase and do it the second way?

I was just curious becaus, especially in history in school, I saw a lot of English quotes translated into German, but still quoted as if they were spoken in German, which I was just curious if this is really allowed since school books **should** live up to those rules, shouldn't they?

Comment: Einstein is often quoted as having said "spooky action at a distance." What he actually said is "spukhafte Fernwirkung." So people do it all the time. But you maybe should give the originals as well (maybe in footnotes) in academic journal articles. I don't see any point in paraphrasing if you give the original, too.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it’s not about English as a language, but rather about the ethics of translating quotes (it may perhaps be a better fit for [philosophy.se], though it may be considered off-topic there as well). It also hinges on what ‘allowed’ means – allowed by whom? In academic writing, it is common to quote verbatim, regardless of language, but quoting Mao and Stalin in Mandarin and Russian, respectively, in a school book for children won’t be of much use.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Maybe it's a style selection by different English publications. Let the question last a bit.

Comment: This has come up before (and, incidentally, closed as off-topic): https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/199908/what-is-the-correct-way-to-properly-quote-and-cite-a-foreign-language-resource

Comment: They are at least three or four standard ways of handling translated quotes in papers. And no one allows or disallows it. It depends on which way one chooses to do it. I'm really sorry to disagree with others here but I most definitely think this is an ELU question as it concerns how to quote **in English** when there is a translation. A good answer here would list at least four possible solutions to this issue. There is not only a single one. How can this not be an English Language & Usage issue? It is very specialized, that yes.

Comment: The use of *[sic]* in the example is wrong. There is nothing that has been left uncorrected that's wrong.

Comment: If you're asking this because it's a concern *for your own writing* (e.g. in an essay, for a magazine article, etc), then this would be suitable to post on our other site [Writing.se] - but be sure to clarify which kind of writing and audience it's intended for. :-)

Comment: @JasonBassford really? I'm no native speaker and all but why would internet be capitalised if it is not in the beginning of a sentence?

Comment: @geekahedron while I agree that this is a similiar question is it, for one, not really answered and more importantly do I believe that my post is of a tad higher quality. Regardless. I do agree with Lambie though, every langauge has its own rules when it comes to quoting (or rather many languages have different rules), and since I want to know the rules for this in the English language, I am asking this here. Philosophy on the other hand does not really tackle the rules of quoting and rather how ethic it would be to translate quotes and hence loose a bit of the quote's original meaning.

Comment: @bv_Martn Proper nouns are always capitalized. Up until 2017, most style guides considered the internet to be a proper noun—it was capitalized no matter where it was located. It's only recently been considered to be a common noun and put in lowercase. This is all a matter of style and not any kind of obvious mistake. (Many people still do put it in uppercase.)

Comment: @JasonBassford what are 'proper' nouns? You did not capitalise any in your post.

Comment: @bv_Martn They are normal elements of grammar, as explained [here](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/grammar/types-of-noun). (And I *used* no proper nouns in my comment.)

Comment: @JasonBassford Ah so it is the Internet like it is Earth and Nature, since they refer to one thing as if it were names?

Comment: The rule I generally go by when translating quotations is to find an authorised translation and quote that and give it as a source. If there is no authorised translation then I translate it myself and give the original language version in the footnote. But like others have said there are different approaches and it will probably depend on what the author wants or whether the publishers have specific guidelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exact treatment depends on the context. In general, it's acceptable, especially if it's obvious that the words are translated. However, there are cases where treating translated statements as if they were written in English is misleading. For instance, there are people who say that the Bible refers to bats as birds and whales as fish, even though the Bible was obviously was not written in English.